# Подсчитать количество потоков в системе linux на python

Tags: python, linux, многопоточность, multiprocessing, threading

Собственно задание, найти количество всех потоков в системе. В приоритете сделать это с помощью встроенных библиотек, но альтернативные варианты тоже подойдут. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: `psutil` пробовали? Там вроде всё есть https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Просто показать кол-во процессов: `print(len(psutil.pids()))`

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибочки

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
len(list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), os.listdir('/proc'))))
```

компактнее

```
import glob
len(glob.glob('/proc/[0-9]*'))
```

Comment: @andreymal можно